# Xamarin forms нет звука

Tags: c#, xamarin

пишу приложение для воспроизведения звука url,
есть приложение xamarin form, использую плагин MediaPlugin версия 0.9.0, targer android 28
в манифесте установил разрешения и так же эти рарзрешния запросил в коде андроид

```
        private readonly string[] _permissions = {
        Manifest.Permission.AccessWifiState,
        Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState,
        Manifest.Permission.Internet,
        Manifest.Permission.ForegroundService,
        Manifest.Permission.WakeLock,
        Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
        Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage
    };

   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        RequestPermissions(_permissions, 0);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        MediaManager.CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();

    }
```

Когда пытаюсь воспроизвести:

```
  private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("http://muziksiz.merakla.com/ama/ama20.mp3");
    }
```

Что в андроид эмуляторе, что через отладку через телефон, появляется в уведомлениях проигрыватель, но звука нет, что я делаю не так?